# changing the data of the element

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I need to change some information in an HTML file and I managed to reach to the elements using JSOUP. However, I faced a problem when trying to modify the following style element:

```
<style type="text/css">
#leftimage {
    background: #FFFCEF 
        url("/image1.jpg");
}

</style>
```

I used the following code

```
Element txt=doc.select("style").first();
String t=txt.data();
String s=" #leftimage { background: #FFFCEF url('/image1.jpg');}";
txt.data().replace(t, s);
```

but nothing changed! Why isn't the color changing when I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String in Java is immutable. You cannot change it. In your case replace() does not change existing text but RETURNS new text with replaced data (read the Javadoc for it).

Actually looking at what you want to do, running replace also does not make too much sense (it substitues any occurence of t with s inside the string you run it on). You basically want to replace the whole text of your element, so you most likely need to do something like:

```
txt.text(" #leftimage { background: #FFFCEF url('/image1.jpg');}");
```